# SQL Return value based on lowest value in another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I've tried to search for a solution to this but have been unable to find one.  I guess it's basic SQL, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a table called people, this table has several columns:

```
ID  Firstname Lastname   Birthdate
1   John      Stevenson  1860-07-30
2   Eric      Johnson    1918-08-25
3   Adam      Efron      1914-02-02
4   Michael   Gray       1870-07-18
```

Now I want to make a query that looks at the Birthdate column, finds the lowest value and returns the firstname of the person that has the lowest birthdate (is oldest).
Can someone guide me in the right direction?
THanks in advance!

Comment: Where's your query?

Comment: Sorry forgot to include that and now I have deleted it :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `order by` like

```
select Firstname 
from people
order by Birthdate 
limit 1
```

Comment: For completeness, it should be noted you can do this in `DESC` order to accomplish the same thing to find the highest birthdate (is youngest): `SELECT Firstname FROM people ORDER BY Birthdate DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Thanks that works excellently.  What do I do to exclude those whose birthdate is 00:00:000?

Comment: @user1088537, include a `where` condition saying `where BirthDate <> '00:00:000'`

Answer (score 2):

This will account for 2 paople having the same birthdate, returning 2 rows.

```
select Firstname
from people
where birthdate = (select min(birthdate) from people);
```

Comment: Thanks that works excellently.  What do I do to exclude those whose birthdate is 00:00:000?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it efficiently would be this ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11e33/2)):

```
select p.*, min(p.birthdate) from people p;
```

NOTE: You will have 1 extra column in the output.